# How to invoke a windows batch file from another batch file

Tags: batch-file, dos

I need to create a batch file that changes path to a particular folder and executes a set of another bat files.

My batch file looks as follows:

```
start cd c:\temp\
command1
command2
```

But it does not work. It just changes path to `C:\Temp` but ignores next lines.

How can I fix this?

Thank you.

Comment: why are you using the start command to do a cd?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put "call" in front of references to other .bat files.  Like this,

```
cd c:\temp
call command1 
call command2
```

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
cd c:\temp
start command1 
start command2
```

Answer (score 1):

dont forget to check if you are really on drive c. try executing a "c:" first before anything else.

```
c:
cd c:\temp\
```

Answer (score 0):

If you take out the `start` command, it should work.

```
cd c:\temp\
command1
command2
```

Answer (score 0):

Just put `CD c:\temp`:

```
cd c:\temp\
command1
command2
```

Or even:

```
cd c:\temp\
start /W command1
start /W command2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
cd c:\temp
cmd /c command1 
start command2
```